# Why is the first entry of an HTML dropdown not present in a PHP array

Tags: php, html

I have inserted a portion of code that includes a dropdown that retrieves a list through PHP SELECT etc. When it retrieves the entries (there are about 3000) in the dropdown, it always excludes the first entry. If I then select an entry, the return result in the form is the previous entry, e.g., if I select entry 10 in the dropdown through a SUBMIT button, the returned result is entry 9. I assume it is associated to the first entry not being present.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Collection Town</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="colltown" 
name="colltown">
                <?php {$sql = "SELECT * FROM `town_info`";
                 $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                 $sth->execute();

                 foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row1) {
echo $row1['id'], $row1['place_name'];  ?>

<option value="<?php echo $row1['id'], $row1['place_name'];?>">
                  <?php }}?>
        </td>
```

Comment: The code is broken. there is no proper closing for some tags. Please edit your code

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, In your dropdown you are not getting first record?

Comment: As mentioned, I have only posted a portion of the code that is relevant @ Sinto. You are correct as only receiving the first recore @suresh.

Comment: you didn't close the tags properly..i have edited your question check

Comment: _Side note:_ You can omit the `{ }` around your code.

Comment: Remove the `echo $row1['id'], $row1['place_name'];` line first of all. With that you are outputting text content inside the select, but outside of the option elements, which is invalid HTML to begin with. Even possible that the error correction the browser has to apply based on that _causes_ your issue to begin with.

Comment: @suresh I doesn't make sense to correct the code inside the question. This way you'd change the question completely. Rather write an answer an explain what tags etc were missing.

Comment: okay @jeff fine thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up your code and order by id ascending to guarantee getting the right order.
also only call fetchAll once initally.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Collection Town</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="colltown" name="colltown">
              <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `town_info` ORDER BY id ASC";
                $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $sth->execute();

                $rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                  echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[place_name]</option>";
                }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
```

Comment: A good answer includes a description of what your solution solves and how it solves it..

Answer (score 0):

You don't close the select tag as a starter, after foreach put `echo "</select>";`
also you don't close option tag's